# gdb over serial port using ppp

Tags: gdbserver

I would like use GDB server over serial port (as i don't have network port)on my Linux embedded board for application debugging? I think i need to have following things in my code..

1. GDB server module
2. PPP(want to use over serial port and i am not sure it is module or application kind of thing which can be used by other application, in our case GDB server)
3. Driver for serial port

Can anyone explain how GDB server uses PPP which in turn uses serial driver?
What are all the changes i need to make if all the above mentioned modules are individually part of my code? i.e how can interconnect all the three modules?